# Is there a way to only run p5.js once an event happens?

Tags: javascript, function, processing, p5.js

I would like to only run the p5.js `draw()` and `setup()` functions once three input fields are all not blank and a button is clicked.

```js
function roundNumber(num, decimal_places) {
  if (!("" + num).includes("e")) {
    return +(Math.round(num + "e+" + decimal_places) + "e-" + decimal_places);
  } else {
    var arr = ("" + num).split("e");
    var sig = ""
    if (+arr[1] + scale > 0) {
      sig = "+";
    }
    return +(Math.round(+arr[0] + "e" + sig + (+arr[1] + decimal_places)) + "e-" + decimal_places);
  }
} /* From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-only-if-necessary */

function computeSelection() {
  const expr = document.forms[0].mathExpr.value;
  var tempAns = parseFloat(eval(expr));
  var roundedAnswer = roundNumber(tempAns, 10);
  var answer = roundedAnswer;
  document.getElementById("output").textContent = answer;
}

function get_x_min_x_max() {
  const x_min = $("#x_min").value;
  const x_max = $("#x_max").value;
  var x_min_x_max = [x_min, x_max];
  return x_min_x_max;
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(300, 300);
}

function draw() {

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <form>
    <label>Graph y=</label>
    <input id="mathExpr" type="text" name="mathExpr" value="">
    <label> from x=</label>
    <input id="x_min" type="text" name="x_min" value="">
    <label> to </label>
    <input id="x_max" type="text" name="x_max" value="">
    <input type="button" name="result" value="Result" onclick="computeSelection();">
  </form>
  <h2>Answer: <span id="output"></span></h2>
</body>
```

If this is my code, I only want the draw and setup at the bottom of the js code to run once `mathExpr`, `x_min`, and `x_max` all contain *some* text and the result button is clicked. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what you want to do you can use the [`noLoop()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/noLoop) and [`loop()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/loop) instruction.
`noLoop()` stops p5.js from continuously executing the the `draw()` and `loop()` resumes it.

Add a `noLoop()` instruction to `draw()`. This cause the loop to be stopped after 1 execution.

```js
function draw() {
    noLoop()
    // [...]
}
```

Add a `loop()` instruction to `computeSelection()`  this cause the loop to be resumed. The `noLoop()` in draw will stop it again after 1 execution:

```js
function computeSelection() {
    // [...]
    loop()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach would be to use **instance mode**.

You can learn more [here](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Global-and-instance-mode), but the general approach would look like this:

```
const s = ( sketch ) => {

  let x = 100;
  let y = 100;

  sketch.setup = () => {
    sketch.createCanvas(200, 200);
  };

  sketch.draw = () => {
    sketch.background(0);
    sketch.fill(255);
    sketch.rect(x,y,50,50);
  };
};

let myp5 = new p5(s);
```

With this approach, you could hold off on creating a `p5` instance until you were ready.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution for myself. Within `setup()` I did:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  document.forms[0].result.click(function() {
    createCanvas(300, 300);
    // Other code in here
  });
});
```

so that the setup only runs on the click.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to start the sketch on a button click for example, expose the function `startSketch()` and add it as onClick event.

`noLoop()` does not prevent the `draw()` function to be executed once but you can work around like this:

```js
let firstIteration = true;

function startSketch() {
  loop()
}

function setup() {
  // other setup you might want to load
  noLoop();
}

function draw() {
  if (firstIteration) {
    firstIteration = false;
    return;
  }
}
```